# Move to left Google Recaptcha v3 Badge

Tags: css, recaptcha

I would like to change the position of the google recaptcha from left to right so that it does not get in the way with the whatsapp button, is it possible using css? Thanks, my page is: https://socialmonkeyagencia.com/

Comment: Please edit your question to add meaningful code (the webpage source) and a problem description (as specific as possible) here. Don't just link to the site - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors if it's changed or goes down. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could hide grecaptcha altogether, if that is what you wanted, below is a css code directly from google on hiding the grecaptcha. With the only caveat being that you need to show the privacy policy links and terms and conditions link somewhere in the user flow.

```
.grecaptcha-badge { visibility: hidden; }
```

Refer:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#hiding-badge